# Why are directories created with permissions 2070 and files with 060 in a directory with setgid bit?

Tags: filesystems, permissions, rhel, acl, umask

I have the following directory:

```
$ ll -d neptune
drwxrws---+ 5 beamin psych 4096 Mar  7 16:18 neptune

$ getfacl neptune
# file: neptune
# owner: beamin
# group: psych
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:sysadmins:rwx
group:psych:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::---
default:group::r-x
default:group:sysadmins:rwx
default:group:psych:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

I am logged in as `beamin`:

```
$ id beamin
uid=1000(beamin) gid=1000(beamin) groups=1000(beamin),2000(sysadmins)

$ umask
0002
```

However, when I create a directory or file, this is what I get:

```
$ cd neptune

$ mkdir dir

$ touch file

$ ll
total 8
d---rws---+ 2 beamin psych 4096 Mar  7 16:25 dir
----rw----+ 1 beamin psych    0 Mar  7 16:25 file
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the answer is in the properties stored in that ACL you dumped:

Why the owner has no permission:

```
default:user::---
```

Why group has rwx:

```
default:group:psych:rwx
```

Why others have no permission:

```
default:other::---
```

This ACL stuff overrides traditional Unixy behavior.

Comment: Group has 'rw' though. How is that explained?